# Is there anything like webBrowser in javaScript in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I want to save a webPage to hard disk with js,but my web browser is chrome,
now I know a similar thing is `webBrowser` in IE,I can use

```
    <object id="WebBrowser" classid=CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2
       height="0" width="0">
    <script>
        document.all.WebBrowser.ExecWB(4,1) 
    </script>
```

to save the web page in IE.

How can I save the page with JavaScript in Chrome?

(My English is poor,wish that you can get what I'm asking.Thank you.)

Comment: This sort of thing is often done in the backend, phantomjs is great for this sort of stuff.

Comment: Is it too heavy? I'm afraid that the code be too long.Or I just need to quote a  js like "src = 'jsname.js'     "?

Comment: If it's just html, and no external links etc.  grabbing the HTML is easy.  document.documentElement.innerHTML;  you could then save this..

Comment: I think I have got it.Thank you!

Comment: I've read it,quite helpful to me.Thanks.